# Enviar sms via php utilizando o número do meu telefone

Tags: php, sms

Eu gostaria de enviar sms via php, porém sem utilizar api de terceiros, eu queria colocar o meu próprio número de celular como remetente e ele consumir meus créditos para cada envio, ou seja, apenas "automatizar" o envio de sms. Isso seria possível ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso você vai precisar de acesso ao SIM, coisa que o PHP não faz, pelo menos não nativamente.

O que eu já algumas pessoas fazendo é desenvolver um app para android, por exemplo, e fazer o envio pelo aparelho e dessa forma consumir os créditos daquele chip. Mas se o volume for muito alto a operadora bloqueia o número.

Mas o jeito correto de fazer isso é usar APIs como http://www.zenvia.com.br/ que são homologados pela Anatel.